# Postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have set up a database using PostgresSQL, the host is set as local host. I want to know how to connect to that database using other software e.g. tableau and to let other people access and manipulate the database, to do this I need the host name/address along with the port number and password, how do I find out the host name/address to connect with? or how do I when creating the server save the host name as something that I can connect to which isn't local host?

Comment: you forgot to mention your platform

Comment: This has nothing to do with postgres at all, and everything with how your network is set up. How is your host reachable from other machines in general? How does it get its IP address on the network that you want to connect from?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what errors/messages do you see?